# Indian father, Bangladeshi mother, baby to be born in Ireland

Tags: indian-citizens, ireland, children, bangladeshi-citizens

This is my first post in this community.

I am an ordinary Indian passport holder, I am in Dublin, doing full-time Ph.D. studies since October 2018 on a stamp 2 student visa. http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/inis/pages/registration-stamps

My wife joined me in Dublin last year January, as an immediate dependent family member with me and she has given me a stamp 2A visa. She holds a Bangladeshi passport.

A baby is expected to be born in September in Dublin. What passport we should apply for, for the baby? Indian/Bangladeshi/Irish?

Thanks.

Comment: You can probably rule out Irish https://www.dfa.ie/citizenship/born-in-ireland/

Comment: https://www.irishimmigration.ie/citizenship/check-if-you-are-an-irish-citizen-by-birth-or-descent/

Comment: One of the parents must have been legally resident on the island of Ireland (including Northern Ireland) for 3-out-of-4 years immediately before the birth. If the baby arrives in September 2021, residence of a parent since October 2018 does not qualify AFAIK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to consider each citizenship separately.

- **Whether the child has Irish citizenship:** No. For a child born on the island of Ireland after 2005 to have Irish citizenship at birth (assuming that the child is not otherwise stateless), at least one parent must:

  - be an Irish or British citizen
  - had the right to live in the Republic of Ireland or Northern Ireland without time limit
  - or have been resident in Ireland (not including in student status) for 3 of the 4 years before the child's birth

  Since in this case you guys were on student status, I don't think you qualify.
- **Whether the child has Bangladeshi citizenship:** According to section 5 of Bangladesh's [Citizenship Act](http://bdlaws.minlaw.gov.bd/act-242.html), the child is automatically a Bangladeshi citizen by descent at birth if your wife is a Bangladeshi citizen otherwise by descent, without needing the child to be registered. If your wife is a Bangladeshi citizen by descent, then the child must be registered at a Bangladeshi consulate in order to be a Bangladeshi citizen. According to section 14, if the child still has dual citizenship at age 21, they will automatically lose Bangladeshi citizenship.
- **Whether the child has Indian citizenship:** According to section 4 of India's [Citizenship Act](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/bitstream/123456789/4210/1/Citizenship_Act_1955.pdf), the child is an Indian citizen by descent if registered at an Indian consulate within 1 year of birth, with the declaration that the child does not hold a foreign passport. (Note: it doesn't matter if the child holds foreign citizenship, only that they don't hold a foreign passport.) According to subsection (1A), the child will automatically lose Indian citizenship if they do not renounce their other citizenships within 6 months of full age.

Comment: Thanks very much for such a concrete precise answer and for clearing all the doubts.